# good 3d libraries for Flash

Tags: flash, 3d

We are looking for free, well documented flash 3d  engine for a new project. What libraries do you recommend? We  will be displaying text and images where images has to be well animated or rotated to some degrees.

We need effects like http://www.cooliris.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For flash there are some open source 3d engines available:

[Papervision](http://blog.papervision3d.org/) will be the most popular lots of demos and tutorials around and this can be complemented with 3D collada models from other 3d tools like blender, maya, etc..

[Sandy](http://www.flashsandy.org/)

[Away3D](http://away3d.com/) has very good demos

[Yogurt3D](http://www.yogurt3d.com/) this one is kind of new and not much info available

Answer (score 0):

1. [Cooliris was not build using flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725489/does-anyone-know-what-cooliris-was-developed-in) (at least not the wall part)
2. Take a look at [Papervision3d](http://blog.papervision3d.org/category/demos/)

Comment: Thanks for clarification Shay.. we too, had question whether cooliris developed using flash or other technologies..

Answer (score 0):

http://www.flashsandy.org/

Comment: Providing a little bit of context around your answer helps people better evaluate what you are recommending. Have you used it before, what experiences did you have with it, is it easy to learn, who is the intended audience?

Answer (score 0):

AS a short comment to this, the Sandy 3D Engine has lots of documentation and tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Either [Papervision3d](http://papervision3d.org/) or [Away3D](http://away3d.com/) will do. For what I have seen so far, there aren't big differences between those two in terms of performance or features.
I would *not* recommend [Sandy 3d Engine](http://code.google.com/p/sandy/) as it's the least powerful of the three.

FYI, on [the blog of my company](http://blog.cycle-it.com/) we're are at the moment publishing [a series of posts comparing precisely these 3D engines for Flash](http://blog.cycle-it.com/category/3d/) (in Spanish, although you can follow the examples and read the source code in English).